# Redirect page to different URL using select dropdown and submit button

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to create a form that redirect the user to a different URL when they select an option from the select dropdown and click the submit button. Here is the markup for my form below:

```
<form>
  <select>
    <option selected="">- Select -</option>
    <option value="https://google.com">One</option>
    <option value="https://gmail.com">Two</option>
    <option value="https://yahoo.com">Three</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Is must be in a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <select id="select_location">
    <option selected="">- Select -</option>
    <option value="https://google.com">One</option>
    <option value="https://gmail.com">Two</option>
    <option value="https://yahoo.com">Three</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="window.location=document.getElementById('select_location').value;">
```

Comment: And the page is really opening?
Not on Firefox / MAC 111.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<form action="yourLink">
```

but if you use onclick as @Oriol Vilaseca suggested, you may need to prevent the submit event:
[event.PreventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: No need to PreventDefault since the type is not a submit. I updated my answer and removed the form tags, which are not necessary.

Comment: I agree but I already had problems with that, thats why I mentioned preventeDefault. Btw removing the form tag I think its closer to what @Breon want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work but not in the SO snippet:

SCRIPT PART :

```
  <script>
    let selectList=null;
    let listButton=null;
    
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getElements);
    
    function getElements(e){
        selectList = document.getElementById("select_location");
        listButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
        listButton.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
    }
    
    function clickHandler(e){
        if(selectList.value!="select"){
            var win = window.open(selectList.value,"_top");
        }else{
            alert("Chose between the three options!");
        }
    }
  </script>
```

HTML PART :

```
      <select id="select_location">
        <option selected="" disabled value="select">- Select -</option>
        <option value="https://google.com">One</option>
        <option value="https://gmail.com">Two</option>
        <option value="https://yahoo.com">Three</option>
      </select>

    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitButton">
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<select>
    <option selected="">- Select -</option>
    <option value="https://google.com">One</option>
    <option value="https://gmail.com">Two</option>
    <option value="https://yahoo.com">Three</option>
</select>
<button onclick="window.location=document.querySelector('select').value;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This works only if the <select> is the first in the document, you need to identify it uniquely.

Comment: @Itzik and Oriol Vilaseca:

Take a look at the message you receive by using window.location.
Run the snippet and chose one of the three options...
The page will not be displayed!

Comment: It works perfectly on my Firefox